# Quelques phrases comportant « formateur en »

Tags: usage, prépositions, articles, coordination

Parmi les variantes ci-dessous lesquelles sont correctes ?

> 1. Formateur en allemand, français et anglais
> 2. Formateur en allemand, en français et en anglais
> 3. Formateur en langues allemande, française, anglaise
> 4. Formateur en langue allemande, française et anglaise
> 5. Formateur en anglais et l'anglais d'affaires
> 6. Formateur en anglais et en anglais d'affaires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les phrases suivantes sont correctes:

Formateur en allemand, en français et en anglais.

Formateur en langues allemande, française et anglaise

Comment: En complément: on dit *anglais des affaires*. *Formateur en anglais et anglais des affaires* est alors correct.

Answer (score 1):

*Formateur en allemand, français et anglais* est la version que je préfère.  Elle vaut mieux, je crois, que *Formateur en allemand, en français et en anglais* qui est un peu lourd avec ses trois *en*.  *Formateur en langues allemande, française et anglaise* peut également aller même si *langue* lui donne un air un peu désuet.

*Formateur en anglais et en anglais d'affaires* pourrait convenir aussi si ce n'est qu'on dit *anglais **des** affaires*.